# ArchUnit: How to check for unwanted dependecies in the signature / API of a class?

Tags: archunit

I would like to implement an ArchUnit rule that checks for unwanted dependencies. That's easy to do but I'm only interested in violations that are part of the signature / API of the class.
E.g. if the class uses an unwanted dependency in a private field or as method parameter of a private method, that's fine since it's not visible from outside.

I'm struggling with the fluent API. My starting point is:

```
noClasses().that()
                .resideInAnyPackage("..domain..", "..application..")
                .should()
                .dependOnClassesThat()
                .resideInAnyPackage(
                    "badpackage1..",
                    "badpackage2..");
```

How can I refine the above rule to only trigger for non-private language elements of my classes?

Answer (score 0):

You could extract an interface and apply the checks to the interface (`classes().that().areInterfaces()`). IDEs provide support for interface extraction.

Comment: Yes, that's the clean solution. For historical reasons, we have some classes (not interfaces) that are considered API and that I'd like to check with ArchUnit.
I also asked this question in an ArchUnit issue: https://github.com/TNG/ArchUnit/issues/390. See there for further hints / answers.