# how to implement a rule that prevent some method's parameters to come from a forbiden package?

Tags: archunit

I'm having trouble implementing a rule that checks the type of parameter of methods of class in a given package.

The rule below, serving as a starting point, checks for method's **return types**.

```
    @ArchTest
    ArchRule ports_must_not_return_domain_model_response = methods()
            .that().areDeclaredInClassesThat().resideInAPackage("..port..")
            .should().notHaveRawReturnType(resideInAPackage("..model.."))
            .as("ports methods cannot return domain model objects - use DTOs and mappers")
            .because("we do not want to couple the client directly to the domain model types of this application");
```

The rule below, borrowing from the rule above to check **parameters** (instead of return type) does not compile because the contract on `notHaveRawParameterTypes` is not the same as the contract on `notHaveRawReturnType`
The later wants a
`DescribedPredicate<? super JavaClass>` while the former wants a
`DescribedPredicate<? super List<JavaClass>>`.

```
    @ArchTest
    ArchRule ports_must_not_take_domain_model_params = methods()
            .that().areDeclaredInClassesThat().resideInAPackage("..port..")
            .should().notHaveRawParameterTypes(resideInAPackage("..model.."))
            .as("ports methods cannot return domain model objects - use DTOs and mappers")
            .because("we do not want to couple the client directly to the domain model types of this application");
```

What is the solution ?

I have check [ArchUnit: How to check for unwanted dependecies in the signature / API of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62589316/archunit-how-to-check-for-unwanted-dependecies-in-the-signature-api-of-a-clas) but it does not give a clear answer on how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

[`DescribedPredicate.`*`anyElementThat`*](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/base/DescribedPredicate.html#anyElementThat(com.tngtech.archunit.base.DescribedPredicate)) can transform your `DescribedPredicate<JavaClass>` to the appropriate `DescribedPredicate<Iterable<JavaClass>>`:

```java
import com.tngtech.archunit.lang.ArchRule;

import static com.tngtech.archunit.base.DescribedPredicate.anyElementThat;
import static com.tngtech.archunit.core.domain.JavaClass.Predicates.resideInAPackage;
import static com.tngtech.archunit.lang.syntax.ArchRuleDefinition.methods;

// ...

@ArchTest
ArchRule ports_must_not_take_domain_model_params = methods()
        .that().areDeclaredInClassesThat().resideInAPackage("..port..")
        .should().notHaveRawParameterTypes(anyElementThat(resideInAPackage("..model..")))
        //...
```